# Are there any frameworks developed over Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, frameworks

I would like to know is there any framework which uses Ruby on Rails framework beneath it.

Regards,
deimus

Comment: I hope that you understand that unlike php Ruby on Rails is a framework. therefore must likely that if there are flaws in RoR they will be fixed with gems/plugins/updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there are, for example [Hobo](http://hobocentral.net/) (but do the world a favor and [don't use it please](http://psionides.jogger.pl/2008/12/02/code-like-a-hobo/)). There are also other Rails-enhancing frameworks like [Cells](http://cells.rubyforge.org/) and [Apotomo](http://apotomo.de/), and "generic controller" frameworks like [inherited_resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) and the (discontinued) [resourcelogic](http://resourcelogic.rubyforge.org/) ([here](http://www.binarylogic.com/2009/10/06/discontinuing-resourcelogic/) you can read what the author of resourcelogic thinks about this kind of frameworks, and why he discontinued it).

The bottom line is: there are many frameworks that build on top of Rails, but you should be very careful when adopting them - Rails is a powerful (if not bloated) framework enough as it is, and in the long run those additions can slow you down instead of helping you.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of things built on Rails that act as frameworks for other applications, although at a different level. Here's two quick examples:

- [Radiant CMS](http://radiantcms.org/) is a full-featured CMS
- [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/) is an ecommerce platform

There are many others. Some of these come as "kit" applications you customize, and others make use of the Rails [engine](http://rails-engines.org/) system to serve as a very full-featured plug-in to any application.